# Why is it incorrect?

Tags: regex, linux, perl

```
$line =~ (m/<Old IP=(^\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})>)/i)
```

I am matching and extracting an IP address. Not sure why is this giving error ? I believe regex is correct.

It is giving me

> Unmatched ) in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/IP=(^\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})>) <-- HERE /

Comment: What error is it giving you?

Comment: @ooga I got rid of ^ still it is giving same error

Comment: Gee, could you possibly have an unmatched `)`?

Comment: @CarlAnderson I have updated with error

Comment: Get rid of that right parenthesis that it's pointing to (and while you're at it, get rid of the outermost parentheses, too).

Comment: You have 2 opening parenthesis -- `(m/<Old IP=(` -- and 3 closing -- `)>)/i)`. Probably the 2nd-to-last is what doesn't belong.

Answer (score 1):

i delete `^` and `)`

```
$line = "<Old IP=5.2.3.2>";
$line =~ m/<Old IP=(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})>/i ;
print $1;
```

output:

```
5.2.3.2
```

https://eval.in/144029